# 'FollowHyperlink' applied to all sheets

Tags: vba, excel

Good morning,

I have been working on a spreadsheet which is designed to be as automated as possible for my non-technical colleagues.

One feature that I am having difficulty with is using hyperlinks to 'open' and 'close' a hidden worksheet. The idea is that only Sheet1 is visible to the user until they click on 'open' (a link in Sheet1) which runs my macro `gotoHidden` (working fine) and reveals a hidden sheet which is named after the Row number where the hyperlink is (sounds more complicated than it is, but this part is working)

When the user is finished viewing or editing the now-visible hidden sheet they should click 'close' (a link on the hidden sheet) which should run my macro `closeHidden`. If I step through the `closeHidden` macro using F8 it performs as I expect it to, but I cannot get it to run when the link is clicked.

Below is the code I have been working with:

```
Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Target.Name = "Open" Then
        gotoHidden
        Else
            If Target.Name = "Close" Then
                closeHidden
            End If
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

I originally created this code, as well as my two macros for `gotoHidden` and `closeHidden`, in the VBA editor for Sheet1, and the 'open' part does work.

I have tried moving all the code to ThisWorkbook object thinking that this would make it accessible from all sheets, but that doesn't seem to work.

I can get it to work if I add the following code to the individual sheet:

```
Public Sub closeHidden()
    ActiveSheet.Visible = xlVeryHidden
    Sheets(1).Activate
End Sub

Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Target.Name = "Close" Then
        closeHidden
    End If
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

However, the individual sheets are generated by different macro (`createNew`) and I don't know if there if a way to automatically add this code to each new sheet as it is generated.

I feel like I'm really close to solving this but I've looked at so many different posts and tried so many combinations I just can't seem to get there on my own.

Can someone see a solution?

Hopefully it's clear what I'm trying to achieve but please ask for clarification if needed.

Many thanks in advance.

**Update:** I've just tried adding the code to a Module instead of the Object which also didn't work. However, adding my two macros (`gotoHidden` and `closeHidden`) to the module allows me to call them from individual Objects which makes things a bit neater and may help me tidy my code in the future.

Comment: If I was trying to apply `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` to an unknown number of worksheets, I would likely try coding `Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink` discarding actions when `sh.name = Worksheets("Master").Name`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely caused because you are using Activesheet in the `closeHidden` procedure, and the active sheet is Sheet1 not your target sheet. You need to use `Worksheets(sheetname).Visible = xlVeryHidden` and have some code to set the variable sheetname according to the row of the active cell.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried to update my post to say I had found a solution but apparently it didn't save the changes.

Similar to what Jeeped has commented, I discovered the difference between `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` and `Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink`.

I was then able to use the following code in ThisWorkbook:

```
Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
Dim shName As String
Dim sheet As Worksheet
shName = ActiveCell.Row - 2
    If Target.Name = "Open" Then
        gotoHidden
        Else
            If Target.Name = "Close" Then
                closeHidden
            End If
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

I had to make a few tweaks to the code I was using to generate the hyperlinks on the hidden sheets, but this is now working.

Thanks to all for your responses.